# error 500 configuration error regarding web.config authentication section after deploying asp.net core to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, web-config, windows-authentication

Framework asp.net core 2.2 -
After developing and managed to get the Windows logged in user in the local host (IIS express):

```
[Route("getUser")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUser()
{
    var NullUser = User.Identity.Name; //return null

    var currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    return Ok(currentUser.Name);
}
```

and LaunchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings":{
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true
    ...
}
```

So far, so good !
Now  - I'm publishing the application to an IIS, with the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <identity impersonate="false" /> //This is because I'm getting the username by code
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <aspnetCore processPath=....... forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" hsotingModel="InProcess">
    </aspnetCore>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled ="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled ="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

These are the basic properties of the application pool which the application works with:
.NET CLR version: No Managed Code
Managed pileline mode: Integradted

Advanced:
Process Model:
Identity: ApplicationPoolIdentity

And then, when running the application, I'm getting **error 500.19** pointing on the authentication section (ignore typo errors - it is free text writing - not copy + paste):

```
AnonymousAuthenticationModule

Config error
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is 
locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set 
explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny"; ot the legacy allowOverride="false"/

Config Source:
<authentication>
   <anonymousAuthentication enabled ="true" />
   <windowsAuthentication enabled ="true" />
```

Comment: Delete all `<system.web>`. They are for ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core. Use IIS Manager to disable anonymous authentication and enable Windows authentication for your site/application, not adding `<authentication>` in your `web.config`. IIS Manager knows the right place to put the settings.

Comment: @Lex Li - , Great, I'll try it. Why can't I see "Windows authentication" in the authentication on the IIS ?

Comment: Probably you didn't enable Windows authentication during IIS installation. You can enable it now.

Comment: Managed - Installed it

Comment: Enabling Windows authentication in IIS: Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn windows features on or off-> Expand Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Under Security, select the Windows Authentication check box  -> Click OK to finish the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

[web.config.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUnwv.png)

I am pretty sure "anonymousAuthentication enabled" should be set to false.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lex Li mentioned - the problem was configuration line items which are irrelevant to ASP.NET core, but to ASP.NET 4.5 - I removed them as he advised